# How to send serial data with some delay in QT

Tags: qt, serial-port

I need to send data via serial communication. This data then will be displayed on a label. I have a com port in my system. I have connected the tx rx line so the data I am sending is the data I am receiving.

```
connect(&Serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(SerialRead()));

void MainWindow::SerialWrite()
{
  Serial.write("2");
  Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
}

void MainWindow::SerialRead()
{

 //reeving data and displaying data on label
}
```

Now I need to send 5 data continuous with some delay like below

```
Serial.write("1");
Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
delay();
Serial.write("2");
Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
delay();
Serial.write("3");
Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
delay();
Serial.write("4");
Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
delay();
Serial.write("5");
Serial.waitForBytesWritten(3000);
delay();
```

So that it is displayed one by one with some delay. How to acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) has static public members to simply delay the execution of the current thread by a specific amount. These are

- [`QThread::sleep(unsigned long)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#sleep) for seconds
- [`QThread::msleep(unsigned long)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep) for milliseconds
- [`QThread::usleep(unsigned long)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#usleep) for microseconds

Comment: The problem is, it didnt display 1st or 2nd message, it waits and display last message

Comment: I fear I can't debug such a behaviour without a COM port and a device I can send data to of my own

Comment: @SAndrew Try also executing `QSerialPort::flush()` after every write.